# java bytecode - no ipush instruction

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

As part of one of my school project I need to dig into java bytecode. I started to write simple programs and use `javap` utility to view generated bytecode and I have one question concerning `*ipush` instructions.

When I view bytecode of this code:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String []args){
    int a;
    a=5;
    a=a+32765;
  }
}
```

I am getting

```
public class Main
  SourceFile: "Main.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
  #1 = Methodref          #3.#12         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #2 = Class              #13            //  Main
  #3 = Class              #14            //  java/lang/Object
  #4 = Utf8               <init>
  #5 = Utf8               ()V
  #6 = Utf8               Code
  #7 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #8 = Utf8               main
  #9 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #10 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #11 = Utf8               Main.java
  #12 = NameAndType        #4:#5          //  "<init>":()V
  #13 = Utf8               Main
  #14 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public Main();
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
    0: aload_0       
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4: return        
  LineNumberTable:
    line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
    0: iconst_5      
    1: istore_1      
    2: iload_1       
    3: sipush        32765
    6: iadd          
    7: istore_1      
    8: return        
  LineNumberTable:
    line 4: 0
    line 5: 2
    line 6: 8
}
```

and when I swap 32765 for 32769 which is not in the range of short I am getting

```
public class Main
  SourceFile: "Main.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
  #1 = Methodref          #4.#13         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #2 = Integer            32769
  #3 = Class              #14            //  Main
  #4 = Class              #15            //  java/lang/Object
  #5 = Utf8               <init>
  #6 = Utf8               ()V
  #7 = Utf8               Code
  #8 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #9 = Utf8               main
  #10 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #11 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #12 = Utf8               Main.java
  #13 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  "<init>":()V
  #14 = Utf8               Main
  #15 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public Main();
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
    0: aload_0       
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4: return        
  LineNumberTable:
    line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
    0: iconst_5      
    1: istore_1      
    2: iload_1       
    3: ldc           #2                  // int 32769
    5: iadd          
    6: istore_1      
    7: return        
  LineNumberTable:
    line 4: 0
    line 5: 2
    line 6: 7
}
```

so now the number is stored in constant pool. I know that there is not instruction `ipush` which I could use to push integer constant to stack, but I am wondering why there is no such instruction?

Comment: It's due to the general restrictions on the size of bytecode instructions. The int wouldn't fit into one instruction.

Comment: @Marko this isn't true. There are arbitrary long instructions (tableswitch, lookupswitch). The real reason is that if you have to specify the entire int, you might as well stick it in the constant pool anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on simple CISC design, they tried to make each instruction as short as possible (in bytes)  Instructions which use 32-bit or 64-bit constants are easier/shorter to refer to a constant table.